# Getting wrong json from twitter API in Android

Tags: android, json, twitter

I've been trying to figure it out how to get tweets from a random user of twitter in Android.

I'm using application-only oauth system. I have no problems with getting the bearer token or authenticating, my problem comes when I ask for the User timeline.

Here is my code :

```
//Getting the data from the twitter api
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    //Append twitter count and screen name with api URL 
                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi&count=2"); 
                    //Append bearer token here.
                    httpget.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token);

                      response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

                      if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                      {

                          HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                         // String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                          //Log.v("result", result);


                          InputStream content = entity.getContent();

                          StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                            String line;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                              builder.append(line);
                            }
```

The result I get from that code is :

```
[
{
    "created_at": "Thu Mar 27 20:10:19 +0000 2014",
    "id": 449277253860352000,
    "id_str": "449277253860352000",
    "text": "RT @TwitterDev: Streaming API will be \"replaying\" some Tweets starting at 1PM (Pacific) today. https:\/\/t.co\/YkpeBC8ixZ",
    "source": "web",
    "truncated": false,
    "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
    "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
    "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
    "user": {
        "id": 6253282,
        "id_str": "6253282",
        "name": "Twitter API",
        "screen_name": "twitterapi",
        "location": "San Francisco, CA",
        "description": "The Real Twitter API. I tweet about API changes, service issues and happily answer questions about Twitter and our API. Don't get an answer? It's on my website.",
        "url": "http:\/\/t.co\/78pYTvWfJd",
        "entities": {
            "url": {
                "urls": [
                    {
                        "url": "http:\/\/t.co\/78pYTvWfJd",
                        "expanded_url": "http:\/\/dev.twitter.com",
                        "display_url": "dev.twitter.com",
                        "indices": [
                            0,
                            22
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "description": {
                "urls": [

                ]
            }
        },
        "protected": false,
        "followers_count": 2106712,
        "friends_count": 46,
        "listed_count": 12572,
        "created_at": "Wed May 23 06:01:13 +0000 2007",
        "favourites_count": 27,
        "utc_offset": -25200,
        "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
        "geo_enabled": true,
        "verified": true,
        "statuses_count": 3485,
        "lang": "en",
        "contributors_enabled": false,
        "is_translator": false,
        "is_translation_enabled": false,
        "profile_background_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/656927849\/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png",
        "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/656927849\/miyt9dpjz77sc0w3d4vj.png",
        "profile_background_tile": true,
        "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2284174872\/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png",
        "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/2284174872\/7df3h38zabcvjylnyfe3_normal.png",
        "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/6253282\/1347394302",
        "profile_link_color": "0084B4",
        "profile_sidebar_border_color": "C0DEED",
        "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "DDEEF6",
        "profile_text_color": "333333",
        "profile_use_background_image": true,
        "default_profile": false,
        "default_profile_image": false,
        "following": null,
        "follow_request_sent": null,
        "notifications": null
    },
    "geo": null,
    "coordinates": null,
    "place": null,
    "contributors": null,
    "retweeted_status": {
        "created_at": "Thu Mar 27 19:32:51 +0000 2014",
        "id": 449267825870262272,
        "id_str": "449267825870262272",
        "text": "Streaming API will be \"replaying\" some Tweets starting at 1PM (Pacific) today. https:\/\/t.co\/YkpeBC8ixZ",
        "source": "\u003ca href=\"https:\/\/about.twitter.com\/products\/tweetdeck\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTweetDeck\u003c\/a\u003e",
        "truncated": false,
        "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
        "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
        "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
        "user": {
            "id": 2244994945,
            "id_str": "2244994945",
            "name": "TwitterDev",
            "screen_name": "TwitterDev",
            "location": "Internet",
            "description": "Developers and Platform Relations @Twitter. We are developers advocates. We can't answer all your questions, but we listen to all of them!",
            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/66w26cua1O",
            "entities": {
                "url": {
                    "urls": [
                        {
                            "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/66w26cua1O",
                            "expanded_url": "https:\/\/dev.twitter.com\/",
                            "display_url": "dev.twitter.com",
                            "indices": [
                                0,
                                23
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "description": {
                    "urls": [

                    ]
                }
            },
            "protected": false,
            "followers_count": 2942,
            "friends_count": 908,
            "listed_count": 50,
            "created_at": "Sat Dec 14 04:35:55 +0000 2013",
            "favourites_count": 60,
            "utc_offset": -25200,
            "time_zone": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
            "geo_enabled": false,
            "verified": true,
            "statuses_count": 199,
            "lang": "en",
            "contributors_enabled": false,
            "is_translator": false,
            "is_translation_enabled": false,
            "profile_background_color": "FFFFFF",
            "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",
            "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",
            "profile_background_tile": false,
            "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/431949550836662272\/A6Ck-0Gx_normal.png",
            "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profil
```

That is all I get, as you can see, the Json is not complete, I don't know why :/ . Can someone help me please? I'll appreciat it. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to your question, but I think your life will be much easier if you use [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html). Works great on Android!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found the solution. The JSON wasn't incomplete, it just showed that way in the logcat (Idk why).
The solution was to make a JSONarray like this :

```
JSONarray array = new JSONarray(resultfromtwitter);
```

And then iterate over it.